# Fixed table height with 4 cells inside (no scroll bars) & assigning text to each cell

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I need to generate a table (HTML/CSS) with 4 cells inside (think 4 boxes one on top of another).
I have two questions-

1. How can i fix the width and height of each box (they may all have different heights) without no scroll bars if text overflows.  If text does overflow, the cell height (& width) must stay same size and hide any overflowing text.
2. Using PHP (No frameworks) I populate these 4 cells with 4 different strings in a database. How can I assign 
   the text to each one of the 4 cells? e.g. $string[1] does into cell#1, $string[2] goes into cell#2 etc.
   Thankyou.

Here is HTML/PHP that generates the table (in a calandar)

```
<table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000"> '
    <tr>'
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">'
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $days_in_month; $i++) {'
    echo "<td width=\"100\" height=\"100\" class=\"$class\">\n";
    echo "<div align=\"right\"><span class=\"daynumber\">$i</span></div>\n";'
    // keep count of cells across row, and if=7 end the row and start again '
    }'
```

etc. (My calendar code works well, unlike my futile attempts to format my code here)

I store "events" in a mySql db, and when i=date in db, I output the text. The complex bit is trying to put 4 different event "data" into their corresponding boxes (see Q2 above).

Comment: could you show us your html/php code OR the generated HTML ?

Comment: I will edit my original question - this "answer box" is too small & saves every time I press enter...

Comment: please read the rules before posting: **"questions asking for debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."** This is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

1. to fix the width and height and to stop overflowing you can use css class.

   .something{
       width: 200px;
       height : 100px;
       overflow : hidden; 
   }

and also you can limit the text length using php substr() function

```
$limitedText = substr($yourstring, 0, 100);
```

2. to do this you have to use a foreach or while loop

   foreach($queryResult as $rs){
      echo "$rs['stringOne']";
      echo "$rs['stringTwo']";
      echo "$rs['stringThree']";
      echo "$rs['stringFour']";
   }